# How to test OpenTK based code with Nunit?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, opengl, nunit, opentk

I want to Unit Test (or, if you please Function Test) [OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com/) rendering results with [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/). I normally use a GameView to initalize and run the application. Unfortunately the GameView seems to lack a public method to render just a single frame which then could be downloaded with glReadPixels and compared to the reference data. How do I best work around this *entering of the main loop*?

Comment: Do you really think this is an unit test? Sounds more like an integration test case. Well, some Test-Frameworks (e.g. TestComplete, http://smartbear.com/products/qa-tools/automated-testing) can make screenshots from running apps (not meant to be used for single unit test).

Comment: Depends on what you do. For example I have an GPGPU implementation to do some image proccessing (mean, histogram, edge detection,...). Now I want to make sure that the computation works properly. Sounds like Unit Testing to me. I can't use OpenCL by the way because the code should also run on OpenGL ES 2.0.